# How to Unlink Previously Linked Sandbox Test Accounts in PayPal Developer

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, sandbox, user-accounts

I visited the Developer portal today and saw the facility to link in Sandbox test accounts. I have 4 test accounts which I have used previously and login successfully in sandbox.paypal.com, but when I try to link them into my live developer account I get the error message:
"Sandbox account you are trying to link is associated with another developer account"
I didn't know I had another developer account. Any ideas how I find it and unlink these test accounts, or somehow move them across?
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If your sandbox account is already linked to another developer account, you cannot link it to your developer account. There is no option for unlink the sandbox account from developer account. You may create new sandbox test accounts and proceed with these.